# SQL Server : matching records from 2 tables with sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let’s assume I have two tables, A and B, both with an ID column and a foreign key (value).

I want to do a select based query that returns only the matching records, not including those that don't meet the condition of having the same data (`ID` and `Value` columns), also sorted by `Value` column of table B.

Table A

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(15, 1),
(16, 2),
(17, 3)
) as t(idMetadata, [Value])
```

Table B

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(185442, 22008, 16, 6 ,2),
(187778, 22269, 16, 6 ,2),
(211260, 24925, 16, 6 ,2),
(251476, 29431, 15, 4 ,1),
(251477, 29431, 16, 5 ,2),
(251478, 29431, 17, 6 ,3)
) as t(idDet, idEnc, idMetadata, OrderValue, [Value])
```

The expected result is

[image]

Can this be achieved by a single query? Or do I have to create a CTE or subqueries ?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention another condition for the query: in Table B, the records should have the same  idEnc and the OrderValue column should be consecutive, That's why the expected result also have same idEnc and the OrderValue is 4, 5 & 6.

Comment: What is meaning of OrderValue? Why 5 is ok for 16 - 5 - 2 (Table B second row from bottom), but 6 should not be included 16 - 6 - 2 (Table B top three rows).

Comment: @kurin123 OrderValue is a consecutive value that shows the order in which the idEnc records in table B were inserted. I edited the question because I forgot to mention another condition, and is that the rows for the expected result should have the same idEnc and also the OrderValue should be consecutive, That's why the expected records have 4, 5 & 6 in OrderValue column and same idEnc.

Comment: So, did you try solutions from answers?

Comment: @gofr1 Yep, yours and Alex Kudryashev' answer worked like a charm ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will give you desired result:

```
SELECT  idDet, 
        idEnc, 
        idMetadata, 
        OrderValue, 
        [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT  b.idDet, 
            b.idEnc, 
            b.idMetadata, 
            b.OrderValue, 
            b.[Value],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.idEnc ORDER BY b.OrderValue) as rn,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.[Value]) as dr
    FROM TableB b
    INNER JOIN TableA a 
        ON b.idMetadata = a.idMetadata AND b.[Value] = a.[Value]
) as t
WHERE rn = dr
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CTE notation

```
;with cte as(
SELECT B.*,row_number() over(partition by b.idmetadata order by b.value,b.iddet desc) rn
FROM (VALUES
(185442, 22008, 16, 6 ,2),
(187778, 22269, 16, 6 ,2),
(211260, 24925, 16, 6 ,2),
(251476, 29431, 15, 4 ,1),
(251477, 29431, 16, 5 ,2),
(251478, 29431, 17, 6 ,3)
) as B(idDet, idEnc, idMetadata, OrderValue, [Value])
inner join
(VALUES
(15, 1),
(16, 2),
(17, 3)
) as A(idMetadata, [Value]) on A.idMetadata=B.idMetadata
)
select * from cte
where rn=1
```

or without CTE:

```
select * from (
SELECT B.*,row_number() over(partition by b.idmetadata order by b.value,b.iddet desc) rn
FROM (VALUES
(185442, 22008, 16, 6 ,2),
(187778, 22269, 16, 6 ,2),
(211260, 24925, 16, 6 ,2),
(251476, 29431, 15, 4 ,1),
(251477, 29431, 16, 5 ,2),
(251478, 29431, 17, 6 ,3)
) as B(idDet, idEnc, idMetadata, OrderValue, [Value])
inner join
(VALUES
(15, 1),
(16, 2),
(17, 3)
) as A(idMetadata, [Value]) on A.idMetadata=B.idMetadata
) t
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with a fairly simple `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    b.idDet, b.idEnc, b.IDMetadata, b.OrderValue, b.Value 
FROM 
    TableB b
INNER JOIN
    TableA a ON b.IDMetadata = a.idMetadata 
             AND b.Value = a.Value
```